# Copy recursively multiple folders as symbolic links except one

Tags: linux, shell

I need to copy multiple folders in a directory recursively with their files as symbolic links for example :

```
[root@tests : /app/dirs]#
|-- dir1
|-- dir2
|-- dir3
|-- dir4
|-- dir5
|   |-- a.txt
|   |-- b.o
|   `-- c.txt
```

I want to copy the content of /app/dirs to an existing directory in the same folder with symbolic links i tried this :

```
cp -as !(/app/dirs/dir3) ./dir3
```

I tried to exclude dir3 because you can't copy a folder in itself but now i get an error saying that the symbolic links can't be created for the files in dir5.

the expected result :

```
/home/barmar/test.dir
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── dir3
│   ├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   ├── dir4
│   └── dir5
│       ├── a.txt -> /home/barmar/test.dir/dir5/a.txt
│       ├── b.o -> /home/barmar/test.dir/dir5/b.o
│       └── c.txt -> /home/barmar/test.dir/dir5/c.txt
├── dir4
└── dir5
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.o
    └── c.txt
```

is there anyway to acheive the expected result ?

Comment: Why are your links in `dir5` rather than `dir3`?

Comment: was ther eany more detail in the error or was it simply "symbolic link for 'dir5/a.txt' could not be created or something like that?

Comment: You could also simply create symbolic links *to the directories only.* Wouldn't that serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!(/app/dirs/dir3)` doesn't expand as you think. `echo !(/app/dirs/dir3)` shows that it includes `dir3`. If the current directory is `/app/dirs`, you can use `/app/dirs/!(dir3)` to get what you want.

```
shopt -s extglob # needed for the extended wildcard
cd /app/dirs
cp -as /app/dirs/!(dir3) dir3
```

This creates

```
/home/barmar/test.dir
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── dir3
│   ├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   ├── dir4
│   └── dir5
│       ├── a.txt -> /home/barmar/test.dir/dir5/a.txt
│       ├── b.o -> /home/barmar/test.dir/dir5/b.o
│       └── c.txt -> /home/barmar/test.dir/dir5/c.txt
├── dir4
└── dir5
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.o
    └── c.txt
```

Comment: I assumed it's already in use, otherwise he'd get a "file not found" error or a bad history substitution.